# Zend Validate - How do you pass context values from a different subform?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I've split up a Form into 3 SubForms and for one of the elements, in the last SubForm, I am creating a Validator that extends `Zend_Validator_Abstract`.

This validator needs to check that a value, on the second SubForm, is not empty. However this value will not be in the `$context` array for the element in the Third SubForm.

What is a sensible way of making this value available in the `$context` across SubForms?

...

After some thought, the only way I can think of doing this is to pass a reference of the parent Form to the Validator's constructor despite it breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also try overriding the **form object** isValid() method and utilizing the $data variable that is available there.

For example:

```
<?php 
class MyForm extends Zend_Form {
    public function isValid($data) {
        // check $data['fieldname'] or add a new validator here, then...
        return parent::isValid($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you use Zend_Filter_Input in conjuction with Zend_form?

Comment: Zend_Filter_Input looks like a striped down Zend_Form that purely handles Filters and Validators. It looks useful if you have a complex form with many decorators and complex validation rules. You could separate responsibility or provide alternative filter and validation, without breaking the base form. Cheers for the tip

Comment: Just a note - it's not obvious whether you are talking about $myform->isValid() or $myvalidator->isValid(). It took me a while to work out you were referring to the former

Comment: @asgeo: Thanks...I up-voted your comment as I over-looked that. Editing now.